# MySQL Like with Array of strings

Tags: php, yii

I have an array of words.

```
$terms = array('bars', 'bar', 'fun');
```

I am trying to find all records that contain each word.

```
TableName::model()->findAll('name LIKE :name, array(':name'=>implode(',', $terms)));
```

Not sure the right way to find all within the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Manquer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25101162/428543) is correct for your specific situation. However, due to the implementation of [`compare`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#compare-detail) (*read the source Luke*) it will not work for partial searches i.e `LIKE '%ADF%'`. For this you can loop through the array and add each element using `compare`:

```
$c1=new CDbCriteria;

foreach($terms as $txt){ 
    $c1->compare('name',$txt,true,'OR');
}

TableName::model()->findAll($c1);
```

---

However should you run into a scenario where you need to add another condition for another group the results may not be as expected due to the way `compare` creates the query i.e you may end up with

```
WHERE ((((type=1) OR (name LIKE '%ABC%')) OR (name LIKE '%RET%')) OR (name LIKE '%Anything else%'))
```

To avoid this you have a couple of options:

1. **Always** ensure your "array condition" appears first.
2. Create another criteria object specifically for your array values and merge this into the other object using `CDbCriteria::merge()`:

   ```
   $c1=new CDbCriteria; // original criteria
   $c2=new CDbCriteria; // criteria for handling our search values

   foreach($terms as $txt){ 
       $c2->compare('name',$txt,true,'OR');
   }

   $c1->mergeWith($c2); // Merge $c2 into $c1
   ```
3. Create another criteria object specifically for your array values and manually add this condition into the other object using `CDbCriteria::addCondition()`:

   ```
   $c1=new CDbCriteria; // original criteria
   $c2=new CDbCriteria; // criteria for handling our search values

   foreach($terms as $txt){ 
       $c2->compare('name',$txt,true,'OR');
   }

   $c1->addCondition($c->condition); // Merge $c2 into $c1
   $c1->params+=$c2->params; // Add the params for $c2 into $c1
   ```

Use (2).

---

Reference: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/610/how-to-create-a-criteria-condition-for-a-multiple-value-text-search-i-e-a-like-in/

Comment: Thanks topher this is actually what I needed, only thing I am worried about are the params sanitized?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CDbCriteria` class  for this sort of Query in `findAll` like this

```
$terms = array('bars', 'bar', 'fun');
$criteria = new CDbCriteria 
$criteria->compare('name',$terms,true,"AND",true);

TableName::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

see [compare](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addSearchCondition-detail) documentation for details

Comment: hmm does this also clean the data incase of injection the way that binding the params does?

Comment: yes it does, that is why the third parameter ($escape) is set to true(by default), it will escape your input, it is there in docs

Comment: @Manquer you mean the 5th parameter. The 3rd parameter for `compare` is `partialMatch`.

Comment: @topher yeah, you are right, by mistake I was seeing the previous function in the docs addSearchCondition and in it escape is third!

Comment: @Manquer happens to all of us.